# difference between classic window service and .net core hosted service ,which one to prefer

Tags: .net, windows, service, .net-core

I have a requirement of reading the data from a table to reprocess the rows for a specified interval of time.
which one should i use either **classic windows service** or **.net core hosted service**.
please guide me on best approach.

Comment: "one runs on .NET Framework, one runs on .NET Core".... since .NET Framework is basically "legacy", and .NET Core is "current and future", I'm going to go with ".NET Core unless you *really, really have a specific reason*

Answer (score 0):

Check windows documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Main reason to choose for .NET core is the scalability and the performance. .NET core 3.0 has a default worker template now, so I would try that in your case.

Comment: hi, can you additionally help me with this question:
Publish the Worker to azure without adding UseWindowsService, still creates me a WebJob in Azure... so What would be the difference in these 2 cases?